# In a shader, what is the meaning of "<some float>.xy?"

Tags: shaders

I'm trying to research this in Unity manuals online, and I'm finding plenty of references to `.xy` but not sure what it is.  While this is for Unity, I'm assuming this principal is more generic across all shader systems.

When we have a `float3` variable called `b` and we say `b.xy` what are we getting?

Is it X * Y?

Is it a `float2`, with X & Y passed through? If this is the case, I'm also seeing `b.xy / a.xy` and I'm wondering how vector division works in shaders.

Comment: There is important feature of packed arrays that has no equivalent in C#:
swizzling.Cg allows addressing and reordering elements within packed arrays in just a single
line. Once again, this appears in the Standard Shader:
o.Albedo = _Color.rgb;
Albedo is fixed3,which means that it contains three values of the fixed type. However,_
Color is defned as fixed4. A direct assignment would result in a compiler error as _Color is bigger than Albedo.The C# way of doing this would be as follows:
o.Albedo.r =_Color.r;
o.Albedo.g =_Color.g;
o.Albedo.b =_Color.b; [Refrence](https://goo.gl/MgT58n)

Comment: @SeyedMortezaKamaly that looks like an answer to me. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Partwise grabbing of each axis.

> When we have a float3 variable called b and we say b.xy what are we getting?

You're getting a float2 that contains [x,y]

This can be expanded, twisted and combined in interesting ways, too:

```
float3 tripleX = a.xxx
float3 reverse = a.zyx
```

> If this is the case, I'm also seeing b.xy / a.xy and I'm wondering how vector division works in shaders.

result.x = b.x / a.x

result.y = b.y / a.y

Answer (score 1):

Unity usually uses a hlsl dialect called cg. What you see is basically a selector, so if B is a float3 C = B.xy is a float2 with C.x == B.x and C.y == B.y .

In cg [specification](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/cg/Cg_1.5/1.5.0/0019/Cg_Specification.pdf) this is referred to as "swizzle operator". (Kudos to DMGregory for this)

Comment: Link to the documentation explaining this would probably be helpful for future visitors.

Comment: I don't seem to find the correct one, but feel free to edit my answer if you do.

Comment: I'd like to add that Swizzling is not only available in Unity/CG, but also in [GLSL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Swizzling) and [HLSL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219869(v=vs.85).aspx)